# tracking Huawei Mifi Model online

Tags: wireless-networking, tracking, geolocation, mifi

Okay, i'm going to try and explain as best as  can.

I want to be able to track my Huawei Mifi device with my phone (using maps) from any location even if I leave the device at home or in the office (provided the device is broadcasting a wifi signal). Please understand that I don't want to have to be connected to the device in order for me to find it.

- Device Manufacturer: Huawei
- Device Type: Mobile Wifi (Mifi)
- Device Model: E5372
- Service: 4G

Comment: What you want ( being able to find it without it being connected to a device ) isn't going to be possible.

Answer (score 0):

You might think you could pick up the external address of the HotSpot with a query from a PC using it to [ipchicken.com](http://ipchicken.com) and track its location based on that IP address, but you will need better data, like GPS (and that hotspot [does not have GPS built in](http://support.huawei.com/ecommunity/bbs/10163627.html)) or picking up another WiFi signal which does have a known location.

There is no [method of associating an exact physical geographical address](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001044.htm) or [the person associated with an IP address](http://www.iplocation.net/) that an end-user can do; so, you need to speak with your telco, the outfit you pay for hotspot service, and ask them if they have a reporting service to.

So, your best bet is to call your telco, the cellular company who you pay for service, and ask their help with geolocation.